# Accurate spacing between images in UIView like in UITabViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have UIView with 3 UIImages in it. (I used the storyboard to draw them)

I don't always display 3 UIImages. I hide and display them like this:

```
facebookIcon.hidden = YES/NO;
```

I would like to display accurate spacing between them.

E.g if there is one image - it will be at the center.

If there are 2 images - there will be one of each side of the center

If there are 3 images - there will be one on the right, one in the center and one on the left.

Similar to `UITabViewController` icons - which are spread automatically with accurate spaces.

How can I do it?

Comment: are you looking to make the resizing animated?

Comment: No. static when displaying them

Comment: you want to do this without using autolayout?

Comment: I would like it to be only on that specific UIView

Comment: Are these UIImageViews of the same size?

Comment: Yes. They are the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the following:

```
- (void)showIconsInView:(NSArray *)channelIcons iconsView:(UIView *)iconsView
{
    int iconsCounter = channelIcons.count;
    int iconWidth = 13;
    int iconHeight = 12;
    int space = (iconsView.frame.size.width - (iconWidth*iconsCounter))/(iconsCounter+1);
    //add the icon image to the view
    NSString *icon = nil;
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [channelIcons objectEnumerator];
    while (icon = (NSString*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:icon];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(space, 0, iconWidth,iconHeight);
        space = space*2 +iconWidth;
        [iconsView addSubview:imageView];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Without using auto-layout or `autoResizeMask` . Not coded in the best way, make the appropriate changes. This assumes `self.view` is the superview for the imageviews and all image views are of the same size.

```
    CGFloat padding = 10; //your wish
    NSMutableArray *notHidden = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (UIImageView *img in self.view.subviews) {
        if (!img.hidden) {
            [notHidden addObject:img];
        }
    }
    int arrayCount = notHidden.count;
    switch (arrayCount%2) {
        case 0:{
            for (int index =-arrayCount/2;index<arrayCount/2;index++) {
                int tempIndex =index;
                UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[notHidden objectAtIndex:index+arrayCount/2];
                CGRect tempFrame = img.frame;

                if (index>=0) {
                    tempIndex=index+1;
                }
                CGFloat xDiff = img.frame.size.width*index+padding*tempIndex;


                tempFrame.origin.x = self.view.center.x+xDiff;
                [[notHidden objectAtIndex:index+arrayCount/2] setFrame:tempFrame];
            }


            break;  
        }
        case 1:{
            for (int index =-arrayCount/2;index<=arrayCount/2;index++) {
                int tempIndex =-1;
                UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[notHidden objectAtIndex:index+arrayCount/2];
                CGRect tempFrame = img.frame;
                CGFloat xDiff = img.frame.size.width*index+padding*index+tempIndex*(img.frame.size.width/2);


                tempFrame.origin.x = self.view.center.x+xDiff;
                [[notHidden objectAtIndex:index+arrayCount/2] setFrame:tempFrame];
            }
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with the code that it's too specific. What if I would have 4 UIImages?

Comment: Wrote the code coz your problem stated specifically 3 images. Lemme c if i can change it to accomodate any no.

Comment: The number of images shouldn't be static

Comment: @Odelya, if you are looking at scalability, you'll have to decide if you want to use AutoResizingMask or AutoLayout. Once that is decided, you figure min/max cases for your variable (in this case, number of images). There's also a case where more than a certain number of images, you'll need a scrollview to show more content. With these decisions made, you or 'anyone giving the answer' would save a lot of time answering the question.

Comment: @calvinBhai I would like to use AutoResizingMask and not autolayout.

Comment: Sorry for that. That code was put in by me for testing. Remove those three lines of code. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Even if you use autoResizeMask or auto-layout wouldn't they resize the views on the absence/presence of views, not if they are hidden or not.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. I believe that I need to play around with it, as I it doesn't work for me - but maybe because I am using it inside UICellView and something is not being loaded properly

Comment: And make the appropriate changes for your code. I'm making some assumptions as listed in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: use [auto-layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) in iOS 6

OR auto resizing [masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) prior iOS 6

```
// auto resizing masks
self.button1.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
self.button2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
self.button3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Please note, that you can do all auto-layout/resizing masks in Interface Builder.

Comment: I am using io6, but autolayout is for the whole storyboard, not for one view inside UIViewController

Comment: If auto layout is enabled you can use constraints to do this for any group of views.But the above code won't stop the buttons or images from overlapping.

Comment: I am not very familiar with it. You can see here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2